# Compare XML tag value vs JSON tag value from two lists for two given paths in python

Tags: python, json, xml

Lets say I have this XML build using xml.tree.ElementTree from a string:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

    root = ET.fromstring("""<statistics>
    <model>
        <name>A1</name>
        <year>1994</year>
        <award>Y1</award>
    </model>
    <model>
        <name>X1</name>
        <year>1990</year>
        <award>Y5</award>
    </model>
</statistics>""")
```

I lets say this json :

```
  import json

    json_data = json.loads("""
   {
        "statistics": [
                        {
                            "name": "A1",
                            "year": 1994,
                            "award": "Y1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "X1",
                            "year": 1990,
                            "award": "Y55"
                        }
                    ]
    }
                    """)
```

And these two paths :

```
XML = 'statistics.model[].name'
JSON : 'statistics[].name'
```

Is there a pythonic way to parse both XML and json for those specific paths and compare the result value for the tags between themselfs for every occurance in a list?

The goal is to check if the value from the XML path replicated succesfuly on the json path, if it did, then print("Mapped succesfuly between XML path and Json Path")

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different topics here:

1. How to a XPath to get elements of an XML tree
2. How to parse JSON path to get elements of a JSON object

### XML

To get the XML names you can use something like this:

```py
xml_root = ET.fromstring(your_xml)
name_elements = xml_root.findall('.//model/name')
xml_result = [e.text for e in name_elements]
print(xml_result)
```

Output:

```
['A1', 'X1']
```

### JSON

There are libraries to work with JSON Path like [jsonpath-ng](https://pypi.org/project/jsonpath-ng/), but here is a naive proposal, using Python `json` module only.

```py
json_data = json.loads(your_json)
json_root = json_data['statistics']
json_result = [model['name'] for model in json_root]
print(json_result)
```

Output:

```
['A1', 'X1']
```

Then you can just compare the two lists `xml_result` and `json_result` for equality.

```py
if xml_result == json_result:
    print('Mapped succesfuly between XML path and Json Path')
```

Comment: But beware that the XML and JSON representations of the data won't always have such a trivial one-to-one relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for x, y in zip(root.findall('.//model/name'), json_data['statistics']):
    if x.text != y['name']:
        print('Mapping failed')
        break
else:
    print("Mapped succesfuly between XML path and Json Path")
```